# OpenCV IOS example Apple Match-O Linker Error with cv::merge and cv::split

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, opencv

I am now learning Opencv on IOS platform, and a good example can be found [here](http://code.opencv.org/svn/gsoc2012/ios/trunk/ImageFilter/). In this example, different image filtering techniques are applied on the image, and this example is a good starting point for anyone who wants to learn how to use Opencv on IOS. However, no matter how I try, I have the following Apple Match-O Linker Errors with cv::merge and cv::split. By the way,  already added the `opencv2.framework` and `libc++.dylib` to the project. Many thanks.

[image]

Comment: check this link http://aptogo.co.uk/2011/09/opencv-framework-for-ios/ follow it step by step to compile a sample opencv application in ios. Probably you have missed adding opencv header files in prefix.pch.